# Apache mod_rewrite rule for complex sitemap + index xml files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, sitemap

We manage sitemap (sitemap.org) files that have in the range of 500k links, which are changing often enough that we want to dynamically generate them, don't worry, we'll cache the results for a period but it's the mod_rewrite rules I'm having a problem with.

Being as we have more than 50k links we need to be using sitemap index files.  Both the sitemaps and the index files will be redirected to a `sitemap.php` file which will use the filename pattern (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) to figure out which list to present.

The filename patterns would be as follows:

```
www.domain.com/sitemap.index.xml
www.domain.com/sitemap.some_theme.xml
www.domain.com/sitemap.different_theme.xml
```

The mod_rewrite covers off our web application as well so I'll include all of it just in case something else may be overriding or conflicting with what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.(.*)\.xml$ sitemap.php/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/ [NC,L]
errordocument 404 /
```

The line I've inserted for the sitemaps specifically is:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.(.*)\.xml$ sitemap.php/ [NC,L]
```

Otherwise everything else is your standard web application stuff.

--- EDIT ---

Ok, so after much head scratching, I found the problem.  First, I simplified the rule slightly since I didn't need to capture the pattern match, only a positive response, the new rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.*\.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
```

So the kicker was simply swapping the order of it and the one below:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.*\.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
```

I'm going to leave the question open for now, because I'd like to know why this made a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is redundant and should be removed:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Modify your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^/?sitemap\. /sitemap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry @anubhava, I was editing my question while your answer came in. There's a bit more than we needed in there, most importantly because our directives are in the vhost file, not an `.htaccess`.  The previous editor added the '.htaccess' tag to the question.  I'll explore the impact of removing the `-d` condition and `^.*$` rule though, a simpler rule set would be great as long as it doesn't negatively affect the rest of the app.

Comment: Ok I made some minor edits above to make sure this anser works in httpd.conf as well.